# Dilemma - How can I overcome a race condition (loop) in validation/workflow rules?

Tags: workflow, validation

I have a validation rule on oppty stage, that prevents our partners from setting it over 0.70.

```
AND( 
Probability > 0.70, 
$Profile.Id = "00e2000000xxxxt" 
)
```

There is another WFR that is based on the stage, that once an oppty reached 0.80, it fires our post sales process.

If my partners want to move forward with an oppty, they are required to use the "Approval Process", which, the second step in the approval process is a field update, of the oppty stage to 0.80.

[image]

This off course causes the error, as it seems that the one that is actually running the approval process is the partner user (and according to the validation rule - he can't set that stage).

> FAILED ---  ERRORS :  (FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION) Can not set
>   Opportunity stage: Please use 'Submit For Approval' ---  for SFDC
>   record with ID : null

```
10:59:11.650 (2650800152)|VALIDATION_RULE|03dD000000xxxxM|Y2014_Dealer_CANT_select_Closed_Won
10:59:11.650 (2650929849)|VALIDATION_FORMULA|AND( 
Probability > 0.70,
$Profile.Id = "00e2000000115ft" 
)|Probability=75 , $Profile.Id=00e2000000xxxxt
10:59:11.650 (2650939760)|VALIDATION_FAIL
```

How can I overcome this condition?

As the requirements are:

1. Partners can not set stage @ 0.80
2. An oppty enters sales process @ 0.80 only
3. Partners must use "Approval Process"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a new text field 'Approval Status' (don't show it on layout)
2. In initial submission action, add a new field update which updates this field with 'Pending'
3. In final approval action, add a new field update which updates this field with 'Approved'
4. In final rejection action, add a new field update which updates this field with 'Rejected'
5. Now, in your validation rule you can add one more condition :

   AND(  Probability > 0.70,  $Profile.Id = "00e2000000xxxxt",  Approval Status != 'Pending' )

Hope this may help.